# php - Java Regex equivalent in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to modify following code for php (for finding simple sequence repeats):

Edit:  The input is like ATAGGAGATATATATAGCGAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGATATCCA
The output here will be pattern, which is AT and CAG, their starting and ending positions.

```
public static String dimer(String d)
{

   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:([ATGC])(?!\\1)([ATGC])\\1\\2)+");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(d);
   while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start Position: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End Postion: " + matcher.end());
    System.out.println(" SSR: " + matcher.group());

}
```

The problem is, while the regex implementation is quite simple in Java, I can't find it's functional equivalent in php(pattern/matcher). Is there any way to implement it in php using regex with minimum amount of code involved ?

Comment: What does the pattern match?  What's your input look like?

Comment: @Madbreaks,edited my question.

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

Your java snippet doesn't match AT and CAG for that input, [it matches GAGATATATATA and ATAT](http://ideone.com/VbokEV).

```
Start index: 4 End index: 16 Found: GAGATATATATA
Start index: 36 End index: 40 Found: ATAT
```

---

This is the exact same thing you'll get with PHP's [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with an identical regex and added [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

#### Example:

```
$input = 'ATAGGAGATATATATAGCGAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGATATCCA';

preg_match_all(
    '/(?:([ATGC])(?!\\1)([ATGC])\\1\\2)+/',
    $input,
    $matches,
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $found = $match[0];
    $start = $match[1];
    $end   = $start + strlen($found);
    echo "Start index: $start End index: $end Found: $found\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
Start index: 4 End index: 16 Found: GAGATATATATA
Start index: 36 End index: 40 Found: ATAT
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me in finding Trimers the same way ?

Answer (score 0):

**See reference on http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php**

```
preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches ...] )
```

**Match example**

```
Array
(
  [0] => Hello, how are you?
  [1] => Hello
  [2] => how are you?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/(?:([ATGC])(?!\\1)([ATGC])\\1\\2)+/";
$subject = "ATAGGAGATATATATAGCGAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGATATCCA";

/*Match regex pattern $pattern to subject $subject, outputting $matches,
  with flag PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, to capture position of first character each match.*/
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

//The PHP documentation has no flag to match the end of the matched string, so....
foreach($matches as &$match) {
    //Add length of the matched string to the starting position of the substring.
    $match[] = count($match[0]) + $match[1];
}
//Unset $match because we passed by reference.
unset($match);
print_r($matches);
```

This outputs:

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => GAGATATATATA
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => T
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 13
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 13
        [2] => 14
    )

)
```

Which is not exactly what you said should be outputted, but I didn't go over the regex itself, and just translated what you were trying to do in Java into PHP.